# How to get the previous selection when selection changes?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an import (from Excel) dialog to select ranges of cells.

When the range is selected, I use the event sink to catch the event and highlight the first row and first column.

I need to unhighlight the previous selection's first row and column.  I don't think it's safe to just get the selected range at the time the selection changes and remember it, such as (pseudocode for brevity and clarity):

```
OnSelectionChange()
 {
 if (m_PrevSelection)
    UnHilite(m_PrevSelection);
 HiliteCurrentSelection();
 GetSelectedRange(m_PrevSelection);
}
```

I'm guessing that just holding onto that range (obtained from _Application::Selection) without releasing it is going to cause all sorts of problems.  I haven't found a way to copy the range (IRange Copy just copies cell contents from one range to another).

I guess I could take the range's cell addresses and store those, then recreate a range from them when I need to do the unhighlighting. This would seem to me to come up often. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were working in Excel VBA, you could

```
Set Rng = Application.Selection
```

where Rng is an Excel Range object. I imagine you could replicate this object from where you are.

Or you could store the cell address in a string variable as you suggested, which of course doesn't require any objects.

Unfortunately, Excel doesn't keep a history of selections.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not expect the range to move or change in size I would store the address and later use Range(myAddress) to return the range object for highlighting.

An address reference will always refer to a fixed area of the sheet whereas a range will be updated to reflect cell insertions/deletions. Either of these may suit your intentions but note that the range reference may become undefined if the cells it contains are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you detect a new range (which you're already doing, to highlight the first row and column), save details of that range to variables somewhere (assuming it's a single, rectangular range, store first and last row, and first and last column).

Whenever you detect a new range after that, you now have stored details of the previous range to use to clear the previous highlights (and this event will store the details for next time, and so on).